# compose Try nicer

Tags: scala, composition

I want to have some utilities to use and cleanup a resource, safely and unsafely, and clean up the resource after use, somewhat equivalent to a try/finally, allowing for cleanup even if the operation throws an exception.

I have

```
def withResource[R, U](create: => R, cleanup: R => Unit)(op: R => U): U = {
  val r = create
  val res = op(r)
  cleanup(r)
  res
}

def tryWithResource[R, U](create: => R, cleanup: R => Unit)(op: R => U): Try[U] = {
  val tried: (R => Try[U]) = (r: R) => Try.apply(op(r))
  withResource(create, cleanup)(tried)
}
```

but I don't like

```
val tried: (R => Try[U]) = (r: R) => Try.apply(op(r))
```

It seems i'm missing some obvious composition function, but I can't see where. I tried

```
val tried: (R => Try[U]) = (Try.apply _).compose(op)
```

but that fails typecheck with

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : R => U
[error]  required: R => => Nothing
[error]     val tried: (R => Try[U]) = (Try.apply _).compose(op)
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you not like `Try.apply(op(r))` or shorter `Try(op(r))`? Sure, `(Try.apply(_: U)) compose op)` looks fancy, but is there any benefit?

Comment: @SaschaKolberg I felt I was writing something that already exists in `compose`, and even though it's a fairly trivial function, writing it twice seemed wrong to me. Then when it didn't work, I wanted to know why.

Comment: More the wanting to know why that the really wanting to have it differently tbh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a type ascription to limit the parameter you pass to `Try.apply` to `U` :

```
val tried = (Try.apply(_: U)) compose op
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but `(Try.apply[U] _).compose(op)` doesn't. Why? (or is that a separate question?)

Comment: I think it's because of the old issue about smallest/largest scope for `_` placeholder ambiguity.

Comment: `Try.apply[U] _` is `(=> U) => Try[U]`, while this is `U => Try[U]`.

Comment: Or just `(Try(_: U)).compose(op)`

Answer (score 7):

You can just use `map`

`val tried: (R => Try[U]) = Try.apply(_).map(op)`

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try

Comment: Like this approach more than one of @PeterNeyens, because there's no extra parentheses around the `Try.apply`. And with alternative syntax for `apply`, namely `Try(_).map(op)`, it's even more concise.

Comment: I also think `Try(_).map(op)` or just `(r: R) => Try(op(r))` looks nicer, but the OP seemed to want to use `compose`.