# What does A => => B mean?

Tags: scala, pass-by-name

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966827/compose-try-nicer/32967950#32967950) I ended up with a value of type `A => => B`. What does this mean?

I've always been led to understand that `=> A` is not actually a type, but a way an argument can be declared to work with call-by-name semantics. But if it's not a type, what does `A => => B` mean?

Comment: Please take a look at #5 in the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802104/some-questions-about-difference-between-call-by-name-and-0-arity-functions . In short `=> A` is a type, but scala compiler does not recognize it. Interpreter often use this notation in it's responses about the type, so you can consider it as a part of type signature

Comment: `A => => B` is a syntax error. Maybe you mean `=> A => B`?

Comment: @sschaef no. The compiler told me `found   : R => U, required: R => => U`

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the compiler. `A => => B` should actually be displayed as `A => (=> B)` in the error message, because a call by name parameter is expected in the return type. However, they are called call by name parameter not by accident, they are not valid as a return type, therefore the compiler should reduce it to `A => B`, which it obviously fails to do.

Comment: @sschaef I think it's worth promoting your comment to an answer.